# Monthly weights on a daily grain

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to write a tsql script that would display five columns. First column is date, second is the day of the week, third is how many of that day in a week exist in the current month, fourth is weight of the day and the fifth is the weight of the month (Mon through Wed get 15 each and Thu through Sun get 10 each). What's the easiest and fastest way to achieve that?

Example output:

```
Date    Day_of_the_week Occurs_in_a_month   Weight_of_the_day   Weight_of_the_month
1/1/2015    Thursday    5   10  370
1/2/2015    Friday      5   10  370
1/3/2015    Saturday    5   10  370
1/4/2015    Sunday      4   10  370
1/5/2015    Monday      4   15  370
1/6/2015    Tuesday     4   15  370
1/7/2015    Wednesday   4   15  370
1/8/2015    Thursday    5   10  370
1/9/2015    Friday      5   10  370
1/10/2015   Saturday    5   10  370
1/11/2015   Sunday      4   10  370
1/12/2015   Monday      4   15  370
1/13/2015   Tuesday     4   15  370
1/14/2015   Wednesday   4   15  370
1/15/2015   Thursday    5   10  370
1/16/2015   Friday      5   10  370
1/17/2015   Saturday    5   10  370
1/18/2015   Sunday      4   10  370
1/19/2015   Monday      4   15  370
1/20/2015   Tuesday     4   15  370
1/21/2015   Wednesday   4   15  370
1/22/2015   Thursday    5   10  370
1/23/2015   Friday      5   10  370
1/24/2015   Saturday    5   10  370
1/25/2015   Sunday      4   10  370
1/26/2015   Monday      4   15  370
1/27/2015   Tuesday     4   15  370
1/28/2015   Wednesday   4   15  370
1/29/2015   Thursday    5   10  370
1/30/2015   Friday      5   10  370
1/31/2015   Saturday    5   10  370
2/1/2015    Sunday      4   10  340
2/2/2015    Monday      4   15  340
2/3/2015    Tuesday     4   15  340
2/4/2015    Wednesday   4   15  340
2/5/2015    Thursday    4   10  340
2/6/2015    Friday      4   10  340
2/7/2015    Saturday    4   10  340
2/8/2015    Sunday      4   10  340
2/9/2015    Monday      4   15  340
2/10/2015   Tuesday     4   15  340
2/11/2015   Wednesday   4   15  340
2/12/2015   Thursday    4   10  340
2/13/2015   Friday      4   10  340
2/14/2015   Saturday    4   10  340
2/15/2015   Sunday      4   10  340
2/16/2015   Monday      4   15  340
2/17/2015   Tuesday     4   15  340
2/18/2015   Wednesday   4   15  340
2/19/2015   Thursday    4   10  340
2/20/2015   Friday      4   10  340
2/21/2015   Saturday    4   10  340
2/22/2015   Sunday      4   10  340
2/23/2015   Monday      4   15  340
2/24/2015   Tuesday     4   15  340
2/25/2015   Wednesday   4   15  340
2/26/2015   Thursday    4   10  340
2/27/2015   Friday      4   10  340
2/28/2015   Saturday    4   10  340
```

.
.
.
.
Say between the years of 2015 and 2020.

Comment: Would be nice to know why the person that voted this question down did it. This question is somewhat challenging and the solution doesn't seem simple either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursive cte to build the date list.. the rest is just window functions

```
WITH cteDates AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2015-01-01') AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
    FROM cteDates
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) < '2021-01-01'
),
cteWeights AS (
    SELECT  [Date], 
            DATENAME(weekday, [Date]) [Day_of_the_week],
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), DATEPART(YEAR, [Date]),DATENAME(weekday, [Date])) [Occurs_in_a_month],
            (CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [Date]) IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday') THEN 15 ELSE 10 END)  [Weight_of_the_day]
    FROM cteDates
)
SELECT *, 
       SUM([Weight_of_the_day]) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), DATEPART(YEAR, [Date])) [ Weight_of_the_month]
FROM cteWeights
ORDER BY [Date]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```